# Zend Framework installation - Does in Linux Apache with drupal installed already needs a restart after zend Installation

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

Does Zend Framework installation Linux Apache with drupal installed already needs a restart after zend Installation - in php.ini

Comment: Depenbds on how PHP is configured. If as apache module AFAIK it needs that. If FCGI, existing php threads only need to be kicked.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, yes. Each change in php.ini - in your case, the modification of include paths, I assume - requires Apache restart if Apache controls PHP. Technically though, it's PHP that needs to be restarted, not the server itself :).

Comment: I don't need to restart apache as I use (F)CGI.

Comment: Like I said: restart Apache if it controls PHP, otherwise just restart PHP.